# How to use count() in serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get count of article likes,but the problem is that i am facing with various errors. Here is my code:

```
class ArticleLikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ArticleLike
        fields = ('id',"author","article",'timestamp')

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articlelikes_set = ArticleLikeSerializer(source='articlelikes',required=False,many=True)
    total_likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','author','caption','total_likes','articlelikes_set')

    def get_total_likes(self, language):
        return articlelikes_set.count()
```

Here is my error:

```
name 'articlelikes_set' is not defined
```

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: `return language.articlelikes.count()`

Comment: That solved the problem.Thanks a lot. If you wish,write it as an answer so i can put a green tick to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`language` is the object you are serializing, hence you return:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # …

    def get_total_likes(self, language):
        return language.articlelikes.count()
```

Comment: I suspect this will do N+1 queries though. Better would be to annotate the queryset on the view with a count I think - maybe django is clever here though?

Comment: @michjnich: yes, that should then be done in the viewset, and then the field is an `IntegerField`, not a `SerializerMethodField`.

Comment: Nah i tested it out,it works fine. It did not show N+1 query anywhere . When the result was 0 , it showed me 0.

Comment: @umarbeyoglu: it will show an N+1 query if you serialize *multiple* `Article`s, for example an `APIListView` of articles.